# What's a simple way of consuming a JSON API using RESTAdapter in Ember.js?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

As a way of learning AngularJS, I designed a [very basic app](http://joao.pt/w/lab/sumup/) that consumes data from a JSON API and simply throws it to the screen (the code is on [Github](https://github.com/joaoramos/sumup/).) Now I'm learning Ember.js and I simply can't get how to achieve the same result. Using as little code as possible, what would be a simple way of consuming data from a public JSON API (e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com`) and routing it to the view?

Comment: Why the down vote? I'd be grateful if someone could point me a better way to describe my question, instead of just down voting. A comment is always helpful in situations like this.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should take a quick run through the guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ajocUPa/1/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com');
  }
});
```

or even less code

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ajocUPa/2/edit

Comment: I did go through the documentation, but unfortunately didn't understand the usage of RESTAdapter. Thanks, your answer is pretty straightforward and self explanatory.

Comment: By the way, it turns out the problem is with the host I'm using. Do you have any idea why it's not working? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/obaTUGaG/1/edit